# Ionic 3 InAppBrowser capture request Pre Load

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I am utilizing inAppBrowser and understand how to subscribe to event observable such as loadstart, loadstop etc. I am trying to figure out a solution for capturing the request made from within InAppBrowser instance previous to it being sent, similar to Angulars HTTPInterceptor feature when making crafted requests from within the app it's self.

As I understand it, loadstart has already committed to sending the request and all you can capture from this is the URL from within Ionic app.

As a solution I can executescript and utilize its callback to retrieve info about a request direct from the browser but this feels like a awkward solution.

Any alternate solutions or assistance would be greatly appreciated.